# awk how to sum all even columns in each line

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file that contains lines of numbers. I would like to print the first column, and the sum of even columns in each line.

Input example:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
5 6 5 6 5 6
1 2 1 2 1 2
```

Desired output:

```
1 12
5 18
1 6
```

Would this be possible using awk or any other tool?

Thank you!

P.S. I do not want to use

```
awk '{print $1, $2+$4+$6}'
```

because my real file has 60 columns

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop that increments the column number by 2 and adds the column to a total variable.

```
awk '{total = 0; for (i = 2; i <= NF; i+=2) total += $(i); print $1, total}' filename
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{for(i=4;i<=NF;i+=2) $2+=$i; print $1,$2}' file
```

**UPDATE**

for timings test, used a 10,000 column data file with 4 rows.

```
$ seq 10000 | paste -s > t && cat t t t t > data
```

tested 3 times each, these are the worst timings for both

```
$ time awk '{for(i=4;i<=NF;i+=2) $2+=$i; print $1,$2}' data > /dev/null

real    0m0.066s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.015s

$ time awk '{s=$2; for(i=4;i<=NF;i+=2) s+=$i; print $1,s}' data > /dev/null

real    0m0.067s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.047s
```

GNU Awk 4.1.4

Comment: That would be less efficient than just using a variable to store the sum since it'll force awk to recompile $0 every time you increment $2.

Comment: @EdMorton testing doesn't show any inefficiency at least with the version of `awk` I used.

Comment: When I try it using gawk 5.1.0 with a larger data set to get into the seconds timing I see the version with a variable consistently being slightly faster but it's not nearly as big a difference as I expected. I can't imagine why that would be given the need to reconstruct $0 every time when $2 is directly incremented. Good (or bad?) job gawk guys on implementing this functionality I suppose?